SFSC Soft error in SFMC Update Account Object activities
I am using SFMC Journey Builder and Account activity to updade consumer status on SFSC side. The Account activity is throwing a soft error from SFSC and it has the following message: AccountsTrigger: System.LimitException: JSON string exceeds heap size limit." and it blocks the update on SFSC side.
It seems this error is a response from SFSC to SFMC, but I am not sure how it could be fixed. Any idea?
Thank you

To resolve the "JSON string exceeds heap size limit" error, you should focus on optimizing the JSON payload, reviewing and improving the trigger logic, and considering asynchronous processing methods.
